Can I apply for UK Skilled worker visa from Germany? I am non-EU student
I am on a student visa in Germany and have a one-year student visa (not a residence permit). Am I eligible to apply for a UK skilled worker visa from Germany with the Germany student visa or do I need to go back to Pakistan to apply for the visa?

AFAIK the UK allows applications from any country where you are legally present and does not have a ‘you must apply from your country of citizenship’ rule.
You apply online here
